# Can not access Hyper-V guest (ubuntu) machine from host (windows 2008)

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I do not know what happened, but for some time I can not access guest from host or host from guest using Hyper-V virtual machine.
I can access both guest and host from any other machine on the network, they can not even ping each other.

```
OS (Host) Windows 2008 R2
OS (Guest) Ubuntu 14.04
Virtualization - Hyper-V
Network settings: Local Area Connection - Virtual Network
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. I needed to add "File and printers sharing" and "TCP 4" protocols on the connection on the host machine.